apply css style to a table in python
I want to apply css style to a table with html but the table apply only the first style (width and border-collapse) and not the second part of the style(padding, text-align)
`file_path="/Users/andreaspagnolo/Desktop/uni/stage/result/result_data_1/final_result"
table_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=\["metric", "result", "average time"\], index=None)

dati_tabella = [
["Silhouette", "correct", str(tempi_di_calcolo[0,0]) + " s"],
["Entropy", "wrong", str(tempi_di_calcolo[1,0]) + " s"],
["Davies-Bouldin", "correct", str(tempi_di_calcolo[2,0]) + " s"],
["Dunn index", "correct", str(tempi_di_calcolo[3,0]) + " s"],
["Calinski-Harabasz", "correct", str(tempi_di_calcolo[4,0]) + " s"],
["Gap Statistic", "correct", str(tempi_di_calcolo[5,0]) + " s"]
]

for row_data in dati_tabella:
table_df.loc[len(table_df)] = row_data

html_table = table_df.to_html(index = False)

table_df.to_csv(file_path + ".csv")

styled_html_table = """
    table {{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }}
    th, td {{
        padding: 100px;
        text-align: left; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }}


""" + html_table

display(HTML(styled_html_table))`

I want to apply css style to a table with html but the table apply only the first style (width and border-collapse) and not the second part of the style(padding, text-align)

Are you sure the first rule did actually apply? I don't see where you are telling the browser here that this is supposed to be CSS in the first place. Assuming that html_table contains the HTML code for the table itself - where are the actual <style> tags to wrap around this CSS supposed to come from ...?

Did you forgot to wrap your CSS in <style></style>?
